# VS Test 2015. В Test Explorer задвоились тесты

Tags: visual-studio, test-automation

В тест эксплорере задвоились некоторые тесты, хотя при двойном нажатии они ведут на один и тот же код. Т.е. 1 тестовый метод воспринимается как 2 теста. Такая ситуация только с некоторыми тестами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема крылась в том, что один(общий) тестовый класс был разделен на два класса. Автоматизатор, который это сделал, решил не переписывать initialize и cleanup, а унаследовал новый тестовый класс от старого. Итого, у нас задвоились тесты в классе-родителе. TFS и Visual Studio воспринимали один тестовый метод как 2 теста.